# Add angular controllers to karma-coverage (Istanbul) code coverage preprocessor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-coverage, karma-runner, istanbul

This is how my project is set up:

```
project/
  assets/
    js/
      app.js
      services.js
      directives.js
      controllers/
        FooCtrl.js
        BarCtrl.js
    css/
    images/
  test/
    unit/
      controllers/
        controllerSpec.js
```

I am struggling to add all the files under `js/` to karma-coverage's `preProcessor` directive.

Doing this

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/assets/js/*.js': ['coverage'],
},
```

only generates coverage report for files directly under `assets/js/` but not for files under `assets/js/controllers/`.

Specifying a single controller:

```
preprocessors: {
   '**/assets/js/controllers/FooCtrl.js': ['coverage'],
},
```

just says 'No data to display'.

Finally, just doing a wildcard:

```
preprocessors: {
   '**/*.js': ['coverage'],
},
```

displays data for all files directly under `assets/js/`, `test/unit/controllers/` `test/lib/` etc. but it still refuses to show any coverage data for `assets/js/controllers/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I swear there is something magical about StackOverflow. I spent an hour getting it to work, gave up, posted this question, and 2min later figured it out.

I made the mistake of moving the files from the `files` array to the `preprocessors` directive. To get code coverage on a certain file, it needs to be in both places, `files` array and the `preprocessors`.

My final configuration that works looks like this:

```
files : [
  //3rd Party Code
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angularjs-scope.safeapply/src/Scope.SafeApply.js',

  //App-specific Code
  'assets/js/app.js',
  'assets/js/services.js',
  'assets/js/directives.js',
  'assets/js/resources.js',
  'assets/js/controllers/*.js',

  //Test-Specific Code
  'node_modules/chai/chai.js',
  'test/lib/chai-should.js',
  'test/lib/chai-expect.js'
],

preprocessors: {
  '**/assets/js/*.js': ['coverage'],
  '**/assets/js/controllers/*.js': ['coverage']
},
```